# Logical Test: Line Shapes

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

What is the logic behind these patterns? What shape should the question mark (?) be in each of them?

First question:
[image: Question 1]

Second question:
[image: Question 2]

Third question:
[image: Question 3]

Answer (score 1):

The first will be:

> [image: ⅃]

Because:

> Taking the shapes' thicknesses, the sum of them in each row is the
>  same:
>
>  2 + 3 + 4 = 9
>
>  3 + 4 + x = 9
>
>  4 + 2 + 3 = 9
>
>  So, x should be 9 - 7 = 2 (the L with 2 lines)
>
>  And it's the mirrored and not the normal L because:
>
>  The 1st, 5th and 9th (shapes) are in the same direction, not mirrored,
>  4th and 8th too in the same direction, so should be the 2nd and 6th,
>  so it should not be the normal L but the mirrored L

The second will be:

> Error: Couldn't observe much.

The third will be:

> One of these:

> [image]

Because:

> The 7th, 2nd and 9th are of the same shape but with different thicknesses; the 9th one's mirrored.
>  The 4th, 5th and 6th are of the same shape but with different thicknesses; the 5th is upside-down, and the 6th is mirrored and upside-down.
>  So, the 1st, 8th and 3rd will be of the same shape, with different thicknesses, but I don't know if it'd be mirrored upside-down, none or both!

Comment: I'm confused: the image version looks fine to me, but although the text version is clearer, understood by screen readers, etc., I feel that, as in the question, it's an image, so not to confuse and not to use text for such a thing, I added alt text so that if the image doesn't load, the text is shown and is recognized by screen readers. Also, sorry; I had to 'Reject' the edit because the other options wouldn't let me edit in the [normal way](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/116437/edit).